# Can I restrict my GCP resources(deployments/services/instances) based on IP range restricted to project/folder/org level?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, access-control, web-application-firewall

I have applications deployed on GCP. My requirement is to:

1. Restrict the above deployments based on the IP address originating from within a project/folder/Org level.

So for example, If I have a GCP project or folder "engg". I want to allow the IP ranges of all regions under "engg" to access the deployments and restrict IP ranges originating from any other source.

Can this be achieved?
The goal is to contain access to resources within my GCP folder/project/org.

Comment: Your post is too broad. Google has a large number of services. Define which service (one). In general, there are several techniques to prevent access from outside a Google Cloud Organization: VPCs and Firewall Rules. However, that is an old-school method of access control. Google Cloud is designed around access control based on authorization and not location (IP address).

Comment: have a look to that part of the documentation. You have Endpoint verification with Access Context Manager. https://cloud.google.com/endpoint-verification/docs/overview It works great but you must activate the feature in your Workspace subscription (and have the correct license to use it)

Comment: @rohitagrawal Was your question answered? If so, please post it as answer so it can be seen by other community members.

Comment: The answers here seem to provide partial solutions.
Since the resources(to be restricted) are open to:
  1. office network/Proxy Server
  2. GCP machines (kubernetes pods/VMs etc)
  3. Private VMs.

    Endpoint verification seems to be good choice but again it would require to be pre-installed from where the request is originating from which is not possible.
Therefore, I want to control the access by whitelisting as below:
  1. IP ranges (for office VM/Network/Proxy) --> doable
  2. IP ranges(or any other way) for requests originating from GCP resources itself.

Answer (score 0):

Per @JohnHanley:

> Google has a large number of services. In general, there are several techniques to prevent access from outside a Google Cloud Organization: [VPCs](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc) and [Firewall Rules](https://cloud.google.com/firewall/docs/firewalls). However, that is an old-school method of access control. Google Cloud is designed around access control based on authorization and not location (IP address)

---

Per @Guillaume:

> Have a look at [Endpoint Verification with Access Context Manager](https://cloud.google.com/endpoint-verification/docs/overview). It works great but you must activate the feature in your Workspace subscription (and have the correct license to use it)

---

Just to add, you may want to consider [VPC Service Controls](https://cloud.google.com/vpc-service-controls/docs/overview):

[VPC Service Control](https://cloud.google.com/vpc-service-controls/docs/overview) enables you to create security boundaries around sets of resources, defining a [perimeter](https://cloud.google.com/vpc-service-controls/docs/service-perimeters) that helps enforce access control policies. However, these policies are based on the identity attributes of the caller, not the originating IP address.